# selection condition in php doesnt work when comparing data from database

Tags: php

i have code

```
<?php

require_once 'DB_Functions.php';
$response = array();
$db = new DB_Functions();

if (isset($_POST['no']) && isset($_POST['semester'])) {

    $no = $_POST['no'];
    $semester = $_POST['semester'];
    $list_matkul = array();
    $response['error'] = false;
    $sks = $db->getSks($no,$semester);
    $list_matkul = $db->getAllMatkulMhs($no,$semester);
    $response['sks'] = array_values($sks);
    //check metode penelitian
    if($semester >= 5) {
    if (array_values($sks) >= 96) {
        $names = array_column($list_matkul, 'nama_matkul');
        $metpen = in_array('matkul_1', $names);
        if ($metpen == true){
        $response['metpen'] = "Mengambil Mata Kuliah Metodologi Penelitian TI, mencari Topik Skripsi pada Semester ".($semester+1);
        }
    }}

    echo json_encode($response,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT); 
}
?>
```

and here is the json output

```
{
"error": false,
"sks": [
24
],
"metpen": "Mengambil Mata Kuliah Metodologi Penelitian TI, mencari Topik Skripsi pada Semester 6"
}
```

why my selection condition at array_values($sks) >= 96 still can run where from json above we can see tht array_values($sks) is 24 and is lower than 96 which is  doesnt meet condition requirement, but when i use <= instead it wont run

this is the code how i get my sks

```
public function getSks($mhs,$semester) {


        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT sks FROM ipk_mhs WHERE no_user_id = ? AND semester <= ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $mhs, $semester);
        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            $user = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
            $stmt->close();
            return $user;
        }}
```

EDIT : what ever the number i put it always run when iam using >= (even if its now lower than 24) so when iam using <=

Comment: Array_values does not return a number so you cannot do a compare like =, <,> because it returns an array like [1,5,6,8]  https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php

Comment: Gues you are looking for $sks[0] or array_values($sks)[0]. Which means the first value on the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

array_values returns an Array without keys, only indexes.
You should compare your array using
`$sks[index or key]`

For example:

`$array = array("size" => "XL", "color" => "gold");`

`$array["size"]` output will be: "XL"